# getpid() incremented by 5 or 6 every time a.out is executed

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, pid

I'm working on *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment* 3rd edition, problem 1 in chapter 1.

Under OS X 10.10.5, why might the value returned by `getpid()` be incremented by 5 or 6 every time the process executed? (In the book, it might increment by 2.)

And why does the value returned by `getppid()` remain the same?

```
> cat getpid.c

int main()
{
    printf("pid: %d\n", getpid());      
    printf("ppid: %d\n", getppid());        
    exit(0);
}

> g++ getpid.c
> ./a.out
pid: 9411
ppid: 6469
> ./a.out
pid: 9416
ppid: 6469
> ./a.out
pid: 9421
ppid: 6469
>
```

Comment: There might be some other process on the system that's creating processes and using those PIDs. Alternatively it could be part of a security measure to try and deter 'viruses' from guessing upcoming PIDs.

Comment: How complicated is your `PS1` prompt?  Does it run commands?  If so, that could account for the extra processes.  I have a constant string as my `PS1` prompt and I get consecutive PID values for the most part (running on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.1, but that's the behaviour I've seen on Mac OS X since Jaguar 10.2).  Your code would more convincing if it showed the necessary headers (`#include <stdio.h>`, `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`) — no C++ compiler will allow you to compile what you show with your `cat` output.

Answer (score 3):

`gettppid` returns the parent process id - that is the process id of the shell you are running under.  Since you keep launching a.out from the **same** parent process, it will keep returning the same process id.  Does that make sense?  Go open another terminal window and run a.out.  getppid will be different on that terminal window.

`getpid` return the process id of the instance of a.out your running. Every process id is unique, but there's nothing in any standard that says these numbers must be incremental or assigned in a predictable manner.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system assigns PIDs as it sees fit. There are no guarantees made about what PID your process might get, except that it be unique at any given point in time. This is what `getpid` gives you.

The parent process of your program – as you run it – is the current shell you're working in. Since it is the same process every time, it always has the same PID. This is the value `return`ed by `getppid`.

Comment: Does it mean that it happens to be incremented by 5 or 6, 'cause it seems it's kind of a regular behavior, lol.

Comment: There might be implementation reasons in your OS that make this behavior most likely. But it certainly isn't something you can rely on.